# Get screen size with Django not using JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html, django, screen

How do I get the current screen size and store it in session using Django? I would like to use different template code depending on screen size, whether it's a full laptop/desktop size, or mobile, etc.

I'm trying to avoid using JavaScript to cater to mobile phones that do not have Javascript on their browsers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
window.screen.height; //screen height
window.screen.width; //screen width

//For example, 1024x768:
alert(window.screen.width+"x"+window.screen.height);
```

You can then store that using either `localStorage` or do an AJAX request to store it in a session.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I made a mistake in my original question. I'm actually trying to avoid using Javascript to cater to mobile browsers that do not have JS on them. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. Let me look into it quickly.

Comment: No, as far as I can see based on my research since you'd be working from server-side (ie, Django) you cannot get the screen size. I'd suggest, however, trying to detect common devices based on request headers. Once you detect a device, you know the screen size. Of course, you'd need a list of devices and screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get and probably parse the User-Agent header from the request. Many devices will send their screen resolution in that. There's a few other ideas on this web page:

http://johannburkard.de/blog/www/mobile/mobile-phone-pda-web-browser-screen-size-detection.html

since it seems some web clients have their own headers for this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers! I eventually used [minidetector](http://code.google.com/p/minidetector/). Seems to be working fine.

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as the approved solution if you work with it?