# Accordion to six column layout with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the following accordion to transition into a six-column bootstrap layout when the screen is wider. I can easily have two set up versions, with the accordion visible in xs and a second version visible in sm and above, but I'd like to keep it to one. Any help and/or tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="panel-group visible-xs text-center" id="accordion1">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseOne1">
         <h4 class="panel-title">ABOUT US</h4>

    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseOne2">
         <h4 class="panel-title">ABOUT US</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


      <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseOne3">
         <h4 class="panel-title">ABOUT US</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseOne4">
         <h4 class="panel-title">ABOUT US</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseOne5">
         <h4 class="panel-title">ABOUT US</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1,#accordion2,#accordion3" data-target="#collapseOne6">
         <h4 class="panel-title">ABOUT US</h4>

    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3z3szvhh/).

Comment: I don't understand the question, what are you trying to do again and what's the problem?

Comment: I just want the content to "come out of the accordion" above mobile width and display across six columns with each div ul in its own column. Basically, how do I pull the content out of the accordion at wider widths.

Comment: do you want an accordion for `xs` and regular `div`s for `sm` and larger?

Comment: Yes, Deja Vu ... that's what I'm going for ... I appreciate your interest/help.

Comment: All, I ended up taking my code out of the bootstrap accordion and using a pure html/css/js solution w/o the aid of BS. Not exactly a solution to this question, but the way I had to do it. ... I will revisit this when I have time - there has to be a way!

Answer (score 0):

1.
The only solution *I can* think of **without** duplicating your code content is to get the device width on server(django) side and render the template with a) ah accordion for `xs` and b) standard `div`s for anything else.
Never done it, but looks like it's [**possible**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779570/get-screen-size-in-django).

2.
The other option is to use [**responsive utilities**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) of Bootstrap:

```
<div class="visible-xs">phone size
    <!-- content in accordion goes here -->
</div>
<div class="hidden-xs">sm and larger
    <!-- same content in standard divs -->
</div>
```

[**^fiddle^**](http://jsfiddle.net/mnrx48yw/)

As you can see, 2nd option requires content duplicate which is a bad practice - refactoring and updating will be a nightmare.

Honestly, I wouldn't use any of the options above, but I thought you want to know about those.
What you can do is probably find the way to "extend" the 2nd option and maybe populate your `div`s from `js` - probably will be massive file.

Anyways, let me know how that works out.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I currently have it set up with one for xs and a second for sm and above, but like you said, duplicate content is what I'm trying to avoid. I will continue to plug away at this and follow up with any progress.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with trying to avoid duplicate content is that you have the data-toggle (etc.) attributes. You could avoid them interfering by moving the ul tags somewhere clean on page load if you detect the correct screen resolution using something like the responsive bootstrap toolkit javascript: https://github.com/maciej-gurban/responsive-bootstrap-toolkit.

Something like

```
  [html contains your accordion as normal, plus this:]
  <div id="accordion-grid" class="row"></div>

  <script>
      (function($, viewport) {
            $(document.ready(checkAccordionSize(viewport));

            function checkAccordionSize(vp) {
                  if (vp.is('>xs')) {
                    //gather the UL tags. for each one:
                    //create a new column in the extra div 
                    //then move the UL tag there. 

                    //when done, use jQuery .hide() to hide the accordion.
                  } 
             }
     })(jQuery, ResponsiveBootstrapToolkit);
</script>
```

For a little more work you could support window.resize too.