# can I get screen resolution request in django?

Tags: python, html, django, screen-resolution

I wanna change some of the following line based on the resolution of the screen(device):

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 and not forloop.last %}
```

no javascript, just django.

so getting the "screen.width" in the **view.py** for example, would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get screen size with Django not using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779570/get-screen-size-with-django-not-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think thats possible nateively with Django:
[Get screen size with Django not using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779570/get-screen-size-with-django-not-using-javascript)

That answer however says you could look at the user-agent headers sent and try and work out what device is accessing the site:
`request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

If its just style changes you want to make or even displaying certain elements are certain screensizes you could use Media Queries in CSS:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp